# Add new filed to Orchard.Roles module

Tags: orchardcms

i need to extend the existing Orchard.Roles module adding a new field to store the Parent of a Role. I would do it from a my custom module, it's possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the roles module has been designed to be replaceable. It has also been voluntarily designed to be very simple. If you need something more complex, with parent groups, you can take the existing module as a starting point, and build your own.